# How do you say "Merfolk" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

The **Merfolk** (or **Merpeople**) are legendary water-dwelling human-like beings. Folklore and mythology have plenty of examples of these beings throughout the ages in various parts of the world.

Some examples could be mermaids ([*Sirenas*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y0lukco) in Spanish) or mermen ([*Tritones*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=aj3cyXA) in Spanish), although "merfolk" could include other creatures that are not necessarily half-human and half-fish in appearance (like the Japanese [kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_(folklore)), the sahuagin and kuo-toa from role games or the humanoid amphibian creatures from movies like "The Shape of Water" or "The Creature from the Black Lagoon").

Etimologically "merfolk" comes from [mer-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mer-#English) <sup>1</sup>+‎ folk<sup>2</sup>.

Is there a word for "merfolk" in Spanish? If so, what is it?

---

<sup>1. sea; marine; applied to beings that are partly sea-creatures:
mercow, mermaid, merman, merswine, mersnake</sup>

<sup>2. people in general; relating to the traditional art or culture of a community or nation. (Folklore is "the knowledge of the people". In Spanish we have both forms [folklore and folclore](https://dle.rae.es/?id=I9k9xD7))</sup>

Comment: Just for the heck of it I tried a roundabout method.  Linguee found a German word, Meeresvolk, which Google Translate converted to "gente de mar."  Not too far off from the idea I originally had, "criaturas de mar." (I thought of *criaturas* because you said some are not necessarily half human, half fish.)

Comment: también tiene *folclor* (forma que suelo usar yo)

Comment: Al googlear "Tritones y sirenas" aparece http://www.jessdharmaescritora.es/mitologia/mitologia-tritones-y-sirenas/ donde los llaman anfibios o "gente de mar". Hay otros resultados interesantes

Comment: OED: Origin: Formed within English, by clipping or shortening. Etymons: mermaid n., merman n.

Comment: Llevo haciéndome la misma pregunta desde que tradujeron "who could the lucky merman be" por "quién será el joven afortunado" en la película de _La Sirenita_. Me preguntaba por qué no usaron "sireno" que habría quedado gracioso. No podían usar "tritón" porque ese es precisamente el nombre del padre de Ariel.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the word for "merman"?

Answer (score 2):

The term "sirenos" is pretty commonly used in spoken Spanish in South America, there aren't a huge amount of legitimate hits on google but it does appear [here](https://www.lavanguardia.com/vivo/psicologia/20171117/432942126588/calendario-sirenos-barba-enfermedades-mentales.html) and [there](https://www.munecadivina.com/sirenas-y-sirenos.php) (that second link is an in-the-wild use of "sirenos" as a translation for "merfolk", check out the graphics on the lower left hand part of the screen)

Comment: **Sirenos** is not on the RAE. Also I guess it is only used by people that do not know the **correct** way (tritón). Could you please be more specific about where in southamerica is that used because in the Colombia region where I live I have not seen it being used.

Comment: This term is in common use among children in Peru and Chile. I have not heard it used elsewhere. The RAE is a useful resource but I do not think the absence of a term of this nature in its database has any bearing on anything

Answer (score 1):

As a Spanish speaker I can tell you that "sireno" is correct; "tritón" is correct too, but the first one is more common, at least in Latin America.

Comment: Pero **sireno** no aparece en la RAE. Además deberías especificar donde en hispanoamérica es común porque en la región de Colombia donde vivo no lo es.